# Compare Mercurial Repos

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I have a bunch of Mercurial repositories on my Windows workstation. We're a small shop, and on some days (usually bad ones) I may make changes / bug fixes in half a dozen or more of my projects. Some of these projects are in maintenance mode, they're only touched once a month or so. Of course, I sometimes get interrupted before I get to push to our central Hg server.

Is there an easy way to regularly compare a bunch of my repos with the central server? It should warn me if I have changes that haven't been pushed. Ideally, something that sits in the system tray and alerts along the lines of "Local change older than 48 hours not in remote repo."

I suppose I should just set up a script to go through my repos and compare them. I could get in the habit of running the script daily.

Thoughts?

Comment: You probably know that `hg outgoing` will list any outgoing changes. But that's not what you're after - you're after an existing tool which will monitor repositories and tell you when you have outgoing changes in danger of going stale.

Comment: @Tom Anderson, Yes, I'm looking for something to automate hg outgoing essentially. Add a little bit of smarts so that it doesn't alert for changes that are less than 24 hours old. It will help me make sure I don't have changes living only on my machine for weeks at a time.  My "low hanging fruit" answer will be to put together a script running on all my repos that I can run once in a while, but I thought there might already be something to handle this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use helper functions in my Powershell profile. They're easy enough in other scripting languages, though I wouldn't dare to do it in .bat or .cmd files.

I keep a file `D:\repos.config` with a list of the absolute paths of all the local repositories I want to quickly glance at for 3 things: status summary, incoming changes, outgoing changes. Examples that follow assume a file with these contents:

```
D:\repository1
D:\repository2
#D:\ignoredrepo
D:\repository3
D:\repository4
```

For checking the status, the script does `$results = hg -R $path st` to get the status list and then I count first-characters only, printing 1 line for the repo path and 1 line for status summary for each repository path (if there's anything to show):

```
----- D:\repository1
  M 1 - A 1
----- D:\repository4
  ? 3
```

For incoming/outgoing, I keep my `[paths]` in each repository's `hgrc` concistent so that the `default` is always the repository on our server, `bb` is the one on bitbucket, etc. I loop through the same list of paths, executing `$results = hg -R $path $type $alias --template '{rev} {node|short}  {desc|firstline}\n' for each.`$type`is either`in`or`out`depending on which I've called and`$alias`is the path alias that should be in each repo's`hgrc`(empty string for`default`,`bb`,`backup`, etc.). I do a little processing of`$results`, since the first 2 lines are not actual changesets. You'd probably want`{date|age}`or`{date|shortdate}` in your template if you wanted to filter out anything less than 24 hours old.

This way I can write simply `hgouts bb` at the prompt and see concise output. Some repositories don't have a particular alias at all, so `2>$null` helps prevent some `abort: repository bb not found!` messages.

```
----- D:\repository2
  150 f7364a6f78d2  integrate FooBar
  151 7a3d3d9fb0d0  fixes #1214; thingamajig wasn't getting closed
----- D:\repository4
  4 dd88f00d93ff  more changes to the doojiflopper
```

As for synchronizing multiple repositories, I'm satisfied enough with TortoiseHg 2.0 and its Repository Registry to help me do them 1 at a time after I use the script to tell me which ones I need to do. But it also wouldn't be terribly complicated to loop through the paths and `hg -R $path pull -u` or `hg -R $path push` en masse, or use bits of the script to selectively pull/push only what's needed that doesn't have changes in the working directory. It's just not something I've needed yet.

**Edit**: I took a bit of time to clean up the code just a little. The functions `hghg` is the status summary, and the functions `hgins`*`[alias]`* and `hgouts`*`[alias]`* are what I actually call from the prompt.

```
function hghg(){
    $repos = [io.file]::readalllines('D:\repos.config')
    $repos | % {
        if (!$_.startswith('#') -and (test-path $_)){
            hg-st $_
        }
    }
}

function hg-st($path){
    $x = hg -R $path st
    if ($x.length -gt 0){
        write-host "----- $_"
        $d = @{}
        $x | % {
            $c = $_[0]
            if (!$d.containskey($c)){
                $d[$c] = 0
            }
            $d[$c] += 1
        }

        $p = @()
        $d.keys | % {
            $cnt = $d[$_]
            $p += "$_ $cnt"
        }
        write-host ' ' ([string]::join(' - ', $p))
    }
}

function hgins($pathalias){
    hg-inouts 'in' $pathalias
}

function hgouts($pathalias){
    hg-inouts 'out' $pathalias
}

function hg-inouts($type, $pathalias){
    $repos = [io.file]::readalllines('D:\repos.config')
    $repos | % {
        if (!$_.startswith('#') -and (test-path $_)){
            hg-inout $type $_ $pathalias
        }
    }
}

function hg-inout($type, $source, $target){
    $x = hg -R $source $type $target --template '{rev} {node|short}  {desc|firstline}\n' 2>$null
    if ($x.count -gt 2 -and $x[2] -ne 'no changes found'){
        write-host "----- $source"
        $y = $x[2..($x.length - 1)]
        $y | % {write-host ' ' $_}
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Joel. I'll try putting together a similar PS script next week.

Comment: Since Powershell is useful for you (the uncertainty was the only reason I hadn't included code yet), I've added what little I use. Hopefully it will be useful.

Comment: Great! I haven't finished customizing it to my preferences yet, but I got it going without any problems. Thanks again...