# Find all Mercurial projects with outgoing changesets

Tags: mercurial

I have a number of Mercurial projects checked out under a common "Development" directory.  What is the easiest way for me to list all projects under this directory that have outgoing changesets that haven't been pushed to the parent repository?  Going into each project directory and running `hg outgoing` isn't ideal.

Comment: assuming each project has its own repository they are completely independent, so going to each and doing hg outgoing is the only solution, though this is scriptable as your answer shows

Comment: If you're on Windows, the answer I got a few months ago has been very nice: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6388088/compare-mercurial-repos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest approach I have found is the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=$(printf "\n\b")
for project in `find . -type d -name .hg`
do
    pushd -- "$project" > /dev/null || exit 1
    cd .. > /dev/null
    if hg outgoing | grep changeset: > /dev/null
    then
       echo `pwd`
    fi
    popd > /dev/null
done
```

**NOTES**

1. If you're using [MQ](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/managing-change-with-mercurial-queues.html) but aren't [versioning the patch
   repository](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/managing-change-with-mercurial-queues.html#sec%3amq%3arepo)  you'll want to change the find command above to
   `find . -type d -name .hg | grep -v .hg/patches/.hg`
2. If you want to list all projects with uncommitted work change the if statement to
   `` if [ `hg status | wc -l` -gt 0 ] ``

Comment: instead non-portable **echo -ne** use portable **printf** (which also built-in for many shells for speed reason)